# Reset Password in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am implementing my own reset password in ASP.NET. In reset password, first I create a random string and mail it to user email.For the link in email like http://xyz.com/account/forgot?random=xxxx&userid=xx.I created a httpget type action forgot which show return a view with input tags for passwords if randomid and userid are validated.
But in httppost type of forgot, I have confusion about the parameters.
I have forgotModel having 2 properties password and confirmpassword.If I just pass forgotmodel to httppost action, then I cannot query user from database.I think I should pass randomId as parameter.But, I am getting how to grab randomID from url of httpget action (If I do so, is it safe?)?
Please guide me, I got stuck..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using SimpleMembership?

Comment: No, I am using custom membership

Comment: Please show the code that you've gotten stuck on (your HttpPost action and the forgotModel).

Comment: i got solution...below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using like Html.BeginForm("action","controller"), If so then you will loose querystring parameters. Since HttpGet and HttpPost methods of ForGotPassword(..) have same action name, **You can just use Html.BeginForm().
So, the form will post data to the page url and you will get querystring along with it.**

in your http post method you can define like,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ForGot(ForgotModel model, string random,strung userid)
    {
     :
     :
    }
```

- If you do not want to follow the above approach, then in httpget method write to ViewBag/ViewData and put them as hidden field in view. Then you can receive them as input to Method.

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult ForGot(string random,strung userid)
  {
   ViewBag.Random =random;
   Viewbag.Userid =userid;
   :
   :
  } 
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult ForGot(ForgotModel model, string random,strung userid)
  {
   :
   :
  }
  ```

and , in view

```
@Html.BeginForm("ForGot","Account"){
:
 @Html.Hidden(ViewBag.Random)
 @Html.Hidden(ViewBag.Userid)
:
}
```

Comment: +1 , In case you are susceptible in keeping the id in hidden field , which you should not , because it is the same as you passed in the querystring , you can also use the Session variable

Comment: @Manas, I don't want to use hidden field,because of suspectible attacks.The first approach can be better.Thanks

Comment: Seems rather trivial to forge the data for the post method and reset an arbitrary user's password?